# How do I define a shadow DOM for any instance of an HTMLElement?

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom

For example, I want all `<p>`s to be affected; without having to change the tag name and without adding `is=""`. Is that possible? I tried:

```
customElements.define('p', MyParagraph, { extends: 'p' }); // or
customElements.define('p', MyParagraph);
// "p" is not a valid custom element name
```

Then I also tried to redefine HTMLParagraphElement:

```
class HTMLParagraphElement extends window.HTMLParagraphElement{}
```

But both solutions didn't work.

I don't want to add the shadow DOM individually to all `<p>`s; I want to add it to any `<p>` that will be ever created, automatically, without having to observe for new elements. If that makes any sense; I know it's a bad idea but I'm mostly just curious now.

Thank you in advance.

edit: also tried

```
class HTMLParagraphElement extends window.HTMLParagraphElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you can only extend to a valid Custom Element name (``namespace-``). The MutationObserver method you mention to change the tag the moment a <p> is added to the DOM is an escape.... Yes, bad idea.. wanting to be a DOM-Dictator. It kinda goes against the whole Custom Element philosophy. Any future developer expects <p> to be <p>. Brings me to another 'solution'.. take the Chromium or Mozilla source-code and create your own browser, where you can <p> as much as you like...

Comment: i find it terrifying that this is something you *want* to do, and i hope you don't find an answer! why not create `<x-p>` as a web component? you could even routinely replace all `<p>` elements on the page with your `<x-p>`